# Wordpress plug-in for a photoblog?

Tags: web, plugin, blog

I use Wordpress for my photo-blog site and currently use [Yet Another Photoblog](http://johannes.jarolim.com/yapb) plug-in to help manage uploading the pictures.

Are there other similar plug-in's that might offer more features.

I'm particularly interested in automatically adding watermarks.

Comment: You might get some answers on the [Wordpress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple options offered by the photo hosting/gallery sites that allow for embedding of images within WordPress blog posts.

- [Photoshelter](http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-4126294-10814042) provides high-end (but very functional) photo/gallery hosting.  They offer the ability to automatically watermark images.  Photoshelter has a WordPress plugin that allows one to search/browse through their Photoshelter images and drop that image into a WordPress post.
- [SmugMug](http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-4126294-10402675) offers similar photo hosting services and also offers the ability to have images automatically watermarked for display.  While they don't offer a WordPress plugin, it's really easy to grab an embed code that will display the photo in a WordPress post.  I currently use SmugMug in such a manner on my photography blog.

I've used both services in the past and can recommend them both as an affiliate.  Photoshelter is aimed more at the pro who wants to optimize for stock sales with great SEO; SmugMug is catered towards both pros and serious amateurs who want great-looking sites with minimal customization required.

Comment: I made an answer but a comment seems more appropriate, SmugMug also has a wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smugmug/ (full disclosure: I work for smugmug :))

Answer (score 3):

I host my images on Flickr, and use the [Flickr Photo Album](http://tantannoodles.com/toolkit/photo-album/) plugin to display them on my site. The plugin can be used to display gallery pages and individual photos, and load Flickr photos in an individual post or page. It's quite configurable, and comes with a load of templates.

Answer (score 3):

I use NextGen Gallery for uploading and displaying photos with wordpress. It also has the functionality to add custom watermarks from text or from an uploaded image. It has a built in slideshow and can manage resizing/cropping once images have been uploaded.

If you do a search for NextGen Gallery in the wordpress you will also find that it is well supported by other plugins that add extra functionality.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation - off to take a look at it

Comment: No problem. I've been working with it quite a lot the past couple of weeks, so any issues feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look at themes rather than plugins. I will have no doubt in recommending following wordpress photo blog them, which I am currently working on deploying for myself.

http://allancole.com/wordpress/themes/autofocus/

Comment: I looked at the autofocus theme that I could install directly from wordpress and was REALLY unimpressed.  It has some serious problems on my install.

Answer (score 0):

I use YAPB for my website, and I run a gallery with ZenPhoto (which can add watermarks).  I was specifically looking for a combo that let me self-host, as I don't really want to turn my images loose on Flickr or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion for Autofocus. I have a very simple one using Autofocus in http://kim.matos-sorge.com/

Comment: Hi Paulo. Welcome to Stack Exchange. If you agree with an existing post, it's better to vote that one up and/or leave a comment to it rather than to provide a duplicate answer. I know you don't yet have the reputation score required to do that, but that's okay; hang around for a bit and post some questions and answers and you soon will.